# (In a graph G)Does the existence of an eulerian circuit imply that there exist a eulerian path for any two vertices in the graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I came up with this lemma that I believe  to be true. But can anyone verify it?(with proof?)

Thank you so much.

Note: it is true that all vertices have an even degree.

Comment: Take a cyclic graph with 20 vertices and 20 edges. Indeed, it is its own eulerian circuit. Now good luck finding a path that starts at 1 and ends at 11.

Comment: @Ivan, of course you mean an *Eulerian* path that starts at 1 and ends at 11. .

Comment: Yeah, of course I mean eulerian path.